# How to delete text notepad++ if it matches

Tags: notepad++

How to delete text in notepad++ if it matches example

test1@test.com

test2@test.com

test3@test.com

test4@test.com

test5@test.com

test5@test.com

test7@test.com

test8@test.com

etc

I have 100 or more random matches I want not only to delete duplicates but delete even the unique line

test1@test.com
test3@test.com``
test194@test.com 
test491@test.com  to be deleted or more

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Place cursor at top of file.
- CTRL-H to Replace.
- Tick Regular Expression.
- In Find what enter `test[0-9]+\@test\.com`
- In Replace with enter nothing.
- Click Replace All.

Comment: the thing is they all are different I just put test for the example

Comment: You'll need to be able to describe the common elements of the text you want to delete. Otherwise, you may end up deleting too much. Your question shows a series of samples that vary only by digits between the word `test` and the character `@`. Do you need something else?